# is it possible to display contents of an external URL through my website?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have a domain, `mydomain.com`, which I would like to display content from another site.  For example, imagine that there is content at this url --> `http://www.foo.com/my/file.bar`, and I would like the content from that page to be displayed when a user visits `http://www.mydomain.com/my/file.bar`, without the user seeing the URL from `foo.com`.

I currently use the following apache directive in my .htaccess:

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [L]
</IFModule>
```

However, this redirects the user's browser to the URL in `foo.com`, which I do not want.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine mod_rewrite with mod_proxy to do transparent redirect (reverse proxy) with mod_rewrite by add P flag to RewriteRule

```
  <IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [P,L]
   </IFModule>
```